# getting vales from different file locations contained in cells Excel

Tags: vba, excel, formula

So I'm trying to create a tracking file in Excel and in cell M5, I have a file location which links to a supporting document and as such, contains some duplicated information so I want to try and pull certain fields (B8 in this example) from the external files referenced in M5.

I have tried `=([M5]Sheet1!B8)` which works to a degree but this brings up a dialogue box and I have to select the file location manually which is too manual for the purpose.

I have also looked into using the INDIRECT function but can't guarantee that both files will be open at the same time, so would prefer another option if possible.

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is formula you can use to get individual cell values from a closed workbook.

It is a User Defined Function (UDF) and you call it like this:

```
=GetClosedCell(A3,B3,C3)
```

The 1st parameter is the workbook path and name.

The 2nd parameter is the worksheet name.

The 3rd parameter is the address of the cell.

Place this function in a standard code module:

```
Public Function GetClosedCell(ByVal FileSpec$, ByVal SheetName$, ByVal RangeAddress$)
    Const CNX = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=[];Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;imex=1;hdr=no;"""
    Const QRY = "SELECT * FROM [.$|:|]"
    On Error GoTo errorh
    RangeAddress = Range(RangeAddress)(1, 1).Address(0, 0)
    With CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
        .Open Replace(Replace(QRY, "|", RangeAddress), ".", SheetName), Replace(CNX, "[]", FileSpec)
        GetClosedCell = .Fields(0)
    End With
    Exit Function
errorh:
    GetClosedCell = "ERROR: " & Err & " " & Err.Description
End Function
```

Here is how it would look on a worksheet:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. It seems ideal for what I am trying to achieve, but I am experiencing a #Value! Error after entering the formula. I have copied the code provided into the standard module and also tried to pull different cells just in case it was a formatting issue. Do you have any ideas as to how I could fix this? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It **is** possible to grab data from an external file without opening it.  For Excel to get a data item, it needs to know:

1. the file *location*
2. the name of the *file* within that location
3. the name of the *worksheet* within that file
4. the address of the *cell* within that worksheet

We enter the required info into some cell, say cell **C3** in a very specific format:

```
'C:\TestFolder\[ABC.xls]xxx'!R9C2
```

*note the single quotes!*

then running this short macro:

```
Public Sub GrabData()
  Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
  Set r1 = Range("C3")
  Set r2 = Range("C4")
  r2.Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(r1.Value)
End Sub
```

will retrieve the data and place it in cell **C4**

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**